# Does adding secondary nodes to the replica set increase page faults?

Tags: mongodb

I am using Mongodb 2.6.x.  I noticed a large number of page faults in mongostat report (CLI).  I am not sure if adding 2 more secondary nodes to the replica set will increase page faults.  The application currently is reading from primary Only.

using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

The Answer  Depends on the read preference on the Primary, in case of read preference from primary only then adding extra replicas should not affect page faults , if the application also reads from secondaries it will probably help lowering down read faults since reads are distributed.